# StreamWriter constructor problems

Tags: c#, buffer, streamwriter

I am trying to do something very simple.

In finding the default buffersize associated with the StreamWriter(string path) constructor too small for the information I am logging, I am attempting to use the following constructor:

```
public StreamWriter(
    string path,
    bool append,
    Encoding encoding,
    int bufferSize
)
```

The resulting log file is completely empty - which is worse.

NOTE: My original post cited the error "Error: Attempted to read past end of stream" , but this relates to functionality later in the method, which I can't log information for because of this log file problem.

Here is the old constructor usage from my code:

```
drawGameBoardLog = new StreamWriter(debugFileName);
```

And here is the new constructor which ironically makes things worse:

```
drawGameBoardLog = new StreamWriter(debugFileName, false, System.Text.Encoding.Default, 65535);
```

I am totally baffled by this.

UPDATE: Some more detail:

This is the start of the method for which I am logging activity:

```
    public void DrawGameBoard()
    {
        StreamWriter drawGameBoardLog;
        bool debug = true;

        // Logging---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Build timestamp string
        DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        string timeStampString = currentDateTime.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss");

        // Build filename, concat timestamp and .txt extension.
        string debugFileName = "D:\\Programming\\PacmanLogs\\DrawGameBoard"+timeStampString+".txt";

        // Create filestream and pass this to a stream writer, setting a nice big buffer.
        drawGameBoardLog = new StreamWriter(debugFileName, false, System.Text.Encoding.Default, 65535);
        //drawGameBoardLog = new StreamWriter(debugFileName);

        // Write to the file:
        drawGameBoardLog.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        drawGameBoardLog.WriteLine("timeStampString = {0}",timeStampString);
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        if(debug){drawGameBoardLog.WriteLine("DrawGameBoard()...");}
```

The line "DrawGameBoard()..." is not even appearing when using the StreamWriter constructor which accepts path, append, encoding, and buffersize. Whereas before I was getting content which took the file size to 1K. Here is the log file up to that point (I'm starting out with graphics programming by the way):

```
19/08/2012 14:13:21
timeStampString = 19082012_141321
DrawGameBoard()...
noOfIndexes = [6], noOfVertices = [4]
...just set stremSize = [80]
...creating vertices DataStream...
...building Matrices...
...Scaling matrix DONE...
...Rotation matrix DONE...
...Translation matrix DONE...
...Orthogonal matrix DONE...
...Perspective matrix DONE...
...COMBINED matrix DONE...
...creating Vector3 and Vector2 arrays to hold positions and texture coords...
...Writing Texture coords....
...Building Index Array (order of vertices to be drawn for a quad)....
...Declaring indicesStream. Set size of stream to [24]....
...Created data stream for indices OK. Now writing indices array to it....
...DONE. Just set position back to ZERO...
...Created new index buffer OK....
...configure the Input Assembler....
...Getting Vectors for position [0,0]...
...Got Vectors into myVectorPositions....
myVectorPositions[0] = [X:0 Y:0 Z:0.5]
myVectorPositions[1] = [X:20 Y:0 Z:0.5]
myVectorPositions[2] = [X:0 Y:20 Z:0.5]
```

The default buffer size kicks in right there.

Comment: Can you show the exception call stack?

Comment: Yes, you're right I'd not accepted any answers. Soz - have since corrected.

Comment: Could you show the code around your error?

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct version of the error? "Error: Attempted to read past end of stream" Attempted to read? Aren't you using StreamWriter?

Comment: Probably this is a typo `System.Text.Default`. Doesn't esixt. Do you mean `System.Text.Encoding.Default`?

Comment: Yep - that was a typo. Corrected it. I've been changing it about - it's not the problem though.

Comment: It looks like the stream error relates to something later which is happening. The fact that the buffer size is too small doesn't actually result in an error being reported.

Comment: Have you tried flushing the streamwriter?

Comment: JTMon - at which point should I flush the streamwriter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not closing your StreamWriter. At the end type:

`drawGameBoardLog.Close();`

Or use a `using` block:

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
{
     sw.WriteLine("Sth");
}
```

Or use a try finally:

```
StreamWriter sw;

try
{
   sw = new StreamWriter(path);
   sw.WriteLine("sth");

}
finally
{
   sw.Close();
}
```

Comment: Yes - the problem is DEFINITELY related to the file not being closed, as direct result of it not being reached. I can track the point of failure now, as I can easily move the Close() call about in the method.

Answer (score 1):

Please change this line

```
 drawGameBoardLog = new StreamWriter(debugFileName, false, 
                      System.Text.Encoding.Default, 65535);
```

in

```
 using(StreamWriter drawGameBoardLog = new StreamWriter(debugFileName, false, 
                      System.Text.Encoding.Default, 65535))
 {


  .... write all the stuff in your log

 }
```

The `using` statement block will ensure that the streamwriter will be closed and written to disk

Probably, your first attempt using a StreamWriter without buffer worked partially, but, when you change the buffer to a big value, then only when you reach that dimension the file is written to disk.

Comment: Ah I think I'm getting somewhere. Basically the close() call was not being reached due to an error prior to that. I have added a premature Close() call earlier in the function, and now when using the larger StreamWriter constructor I am now getting logging information.

Comment: This is one of the reasons to use the `using` statement. You could forget the Close() because every path from your code (exception included) will be handled by the closing brace of the using statement.